# Unpivot coumns into rows - PL/ SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have the following table - with a lot of rows -

```
ID  A_1  B_1  A_2  B_2   A_3  B_3
--  ----  ---  ---  ----  ---  ---
 1   0     0     0    0    0    0
 2   1     0     0    0    0    0
```

I need to get the following output table -
the rows will be ID, A_1, B_1  and so on.

```
ID    A    B
---   --  --
1     0    0
1     0    0
1     0    0
2     1    0
2     0    0 
2     0    0
```

I tried with union, unpivot - I get only one row  for each ID instead three.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Union all to include the duplicate:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f3af2/6)

Result:

[image]

```
SELECT ID, A_1 A, B_1 B FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, A_2, B_2 FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, A_3, B_3 FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: I tried not the output that I need. I got only one row and not three. The union is not good in this case of same values.

Comment: have you checked  the demo, I have not used UNION but UNION ALL.

Comment: Edited the answer with screenshot of result from SQLFIDDLE.

Comment: thanks for your help :) union all solve the duplicates

Comment: Union-all solution requires 3 table scans, while unpivot just 1

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select *
from t
unpivot (
  (A,B) 
     for z in ( 
               (A_1,  B_1),
               (A_2 , B_2),
               (A_3,  B_3)
              )
);
```

Full test case with the results:

```sql
with t (ID, A_1,  B_1,  A_2 , B_2 ,  A_3,  B_3) as (
select 1,  0 ,    0,     0,    0,    0,    0 from dual union all
select 2,  1 ,    0,     0,    0,    0,    0 from dual
)
select *
from t
unpivot (
  (A,B) 
     for z in ( 
               (A_1,  B_1),
               (A_2 , B_2),
               (A_3,  B_3)
              )
);
```

Results:

```
        ID Z                A          B
---------- ------- ---------- ----------
         1 A_1_B_1          0          0
         1 A_2_B_2          0          0
         1 A_3_B_3          0          0
         2 A_1_B_1          1          0
         2 A_2_B_2          0          0
         2 A_3_B_3          0          0
```